# Rails helper to strip only the first a tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I've an issue to solve.

In my CMS I have a sort of enhanced title with this HTML structure

```
<h1><a href="http://...">This is the new Tesla.<span class="huge-title">Wow, 500 miles</span></a> | <a href="http://...">Video</a> | <a href="http://...">Gallery</a></h1>
```

## [This is the new Tesla.Wow, 500 miles](http://...) | [Video](http://...) | [Gallery](http://...)

I use this enhanced title for the teaser in home page. The first link is related to the content, video & gallery link to other content that are on a different page, so three different link.

Of course when someone click on the content I cannot use the same title inside the blog post because I have the anchor tag.

I need to write an helper that keep just the content of the first anchor tag, so

```
This is the new Tesla.<span class="huge-title">Wow, 500 miles</span>
```

Any hint?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/comfy/active_link_to this gem helps you?

Comment: No, I'm creating the link using a wysiwyg editor not with the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
original_title = '<h1><a href="http://...">This is the new Tesla.<span class="huge-title">Wow, 500 miles</span></a> | <a href="http://...">Video</a> | <a href="http://...">Gallery</a></h1>'

match = original_title.match(/^<h1><a href.*?>(.*?<\/span>)/)


puts match[1]

This is the new Tesla.<span class="huge-title">Wow, 500 miles</span>
```

If the `span` can come anywhere you just need to tweak the logic a bit

```
match = original_title.match(/^<h1><a href.*?>(.*?<\/a>)/)

puts match[1].gsub('</a>', '')

This is the new Tesla.<span class="huge-title">Wow, 500 miles</span>
```

Basically you're saying, match a string starting with `<h1><a href` (indicated by `^`), followed by any number of characters until you find the first `>`(which will be the closing `>` of the anchor tag), then immediately after capture a group (indicated by the unescaped curved parenthesis), with any number of characters, indicated by `.*`, until you find the first occurrence of `</span>`, indicated by the `?` (without `?` if you had more closing span tags it would match everything until the last span tag, this way it's non-greedy and stops at the first occurrence of what you after it). This will return you an array of matches, the first index of which is the total captured content, and the remaining each individual capture group. In this case you want the second item, since it's the capture group.

Comment: I try but sometimes the span is in the middle, sometimes at the end. Basically the span is used to evidence some block of the title by the author. Maybe is better to use nokogiri to find the first a and get the content

Comment: Yeah you would have to write a more complex regex, or strip the title from the span tags before matching. With nokogiri it's pretty much more straightforward since you can find the first `<a>` and just extract `.text` from the node or `.inner_html` if you want to keep the spans inside.

Comment: You can also just change what is the final part of the match, so instead of matching on the first `</span>` you match on the first `</a>`, and then gsub it out